# e is undefined error when workflow runs

Tags: javascript, .net, html, esri

I have a workflow that is triggered from another server to launch my mapping app and run a query for a parcel polygon. It seems to work fine in Chrome and IE, but in Firefox it throws an error "e is undefined". Not sure what to look for in my code.

Any help appreciated -Jim

```
Activity mc:Ignorable="sads sap sap2010" x:Class="ActivityBuilder"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:eac="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client"
 xmlns:eacg="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client"
 xmlns:eact="clr-namespace:ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks;assembly=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client"
 xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
 xmlns:gce="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Core.Extensions;assembly=Geocortex.Core"
 xmlns:gfc="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Forms.Client;assembly=Geocortex.EssentialsWpfApi"
 xmlns:gfci="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Forms.Client.Items;assembly=Geocortex.EssentialsWpfApi"
 xmlns:gr="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Reporting;assembly=Geocortex.Reporting"
 xmlns:gwa="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Geocortex.Workflow"
 xmlns:gwa1="clr-namespace:Geocortex.Workflow.Activities;assembly=Geocortex.Workflow.Activities"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
 xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:sap2010="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sco="clr-namespace:System.Collections.ObjectModel;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="id" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="wkid" Type="esri:SpatialReference" />
    <x:Property Name="BufferedParcel" Type="OutArgument(esri:Graphic)" />
  </x:Members>
  <mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
    <x:Null />
  </mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
  <sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef>ActivityBuilder_1</sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef>
  <TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="x:String">
      <x:String>System.Activities.XamlIntegration</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Validation</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Statements</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Activities.Expressions</x:String>
      <x:String>ESRI.ArcGIS.Client</x:String>
      <x:String>ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry</x:String>
      <x:String>ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks</x:String>
      <x:String>Geocortex.Core.Extensions</x:String>
      <x:String>Geocortex.Workflow.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>Geocortex.Forms.Client</x:String>
      <x:String>Geocortex.Forms.Client.Items</x:String>
      <x:String>Geocortex.Reporting</x:String>
      <x:String>System</x:String>
      <x:String>Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Collections.Generic</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Linq</x:String>
      <x:String>System.Windows.Markup</x:String>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.NamespacesForImplementation>
  <TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
    <sco:Collection x:TypeArguments="AssemblyReference">
      <AssemblyReference>System.Activities</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>ESRI.ArcGIS.Client</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Geocortex.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Geocortex.Workflow</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Geocortex.EssentialsWpfApi</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>Geocortex.Reporting</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>mscorlib</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationFramework</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>WindowsBase</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>PresentationCore</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Xaml</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ServiceModel</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.Reactive.Core</AssemblyReference>
      <AssemblyReference>System.ComponentModel.Composition</AssemblyReference>
    </sco:Collection>
  </TextExpression.ReferencesForImplementation>
  <Sequence sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_1" mva:VisualBasic.Settings="Assembly references and imported namespaces serialized as XML namespaces">
    <Sequence.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:FeatureSet" Name="ReturnedParcel" />
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope" Name="ParcelExtent" />
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="46" Name="mapServiceID" />
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/PROPERTY2/MapServer/0" Name="queryServiceURL" />
    </Sequence.Variables>
    <Flowchart sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Flowchart_1">
      <Flowchart.Variables>
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/PROPERTY2/MapServer/3" Name="retiredQueryServiceUrl" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="3" Name="retiredLayerID" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="0" Name="layerID" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:SpatialReference" Name="wkid" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="variable1" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:Geometry" Name="bufferResultGeom" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:FeatureSet" Name="BufferedParcels" />
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope" Name="bufferExtent" />
      </Flowchart.Variables>
      <Flowchart.StartNode>
        <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID0" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_3">
          <gwa1:QueryTask sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="QueryTask_2" OutFields="*" OutSpatialReference="[wkid]" QueryServiceUrl="[queryServiceUrl]" Results="[ReturnedParcel]" ReturnGeometry="True" Where="[&quot;TaxKey = '&quot; &amp; id &amp; &quot;'&quot;]" />
          <FlowStep.Next>
            <FlowDecision x:Name="__ReferenceID3" Condition="[ReturnedParcel.Features.Count &gt; 0]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowDecision_1">
              <FlowDecision.True>
                <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID10" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_18">
                  <Sequence DisplayName="BufferSequence" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_5">
                    <Sequence.Variables>
                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="variable2" />
                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IEnumerable(esri:Graphic)" Name="bufferResult" />
                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer" Name="geometryServiceUri" />
                      <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IList(esri:Graphic)" Name="bufferResult2" />
                    </Sequence.Variables>
                    <gwa1:BufferTask BufferSpatialReference="[wkid]" Distance="10" FeatureSet="[ReturnedParcel]" GeometryServiceUrl="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="BufferTask_2" OutSpatialReference="[wkid]" Results="[bufferResult]" Unit="[ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.LinearUnit.Foot]" />
                    <gwa1:ProjectTask FeatureSet="[bufferResult]" GeometryServiceUrl="[geometryServiceUri]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ProjectTask_1" Results="[bufferResult2]" SpatialReference="[new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(32054)]" />
                    <Assign sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Assign_1">
                      <Assign.To>
                        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Geometry">[bufferResultGeom]</OutArgument>
                      </Assign.To>
                      <Assign.Value>
                        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Geometry">[bufferResult2.First().Geometry]</InArgument>
                      </Assign.Value>
                    </Assign>
                    <Assign sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Assign_2">
                      <Assign.To>
                        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope">[bufferExtent]</OutArgument>
                      </Assign.To>
                      <Assign.Value>
                        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope">[bufferResultGeom.Extent.Expand(2)]</InArgument>
                      </Assign.Value>
                    </Assign>
                  </Sequence>
                  <FlowStep.Next>
                    <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID1" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_1">
                      <gwa1:SelectFeatures ClearCollectionFirst="True" FeatureSet="[ReturnedParcel]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="SelectFeatures_2" LayerId="[layerID]" MapServiceId="[mapServiceID]" />
                      <FlowStep.Next>
                        <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID11" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_20">
                          <gwa1:RunExternalCommand CommandName="HighlightEsriFeatureSet" CommandParameter="[ReturnedParcel]" DisplayName="Highlight Features" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="RunExternalCommand_12" />
                          <FlowStep.Next>
                            <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID9" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_15">
                              <gwa1:RunExternalCommand CommandName="ZoomToExtent" CommandParameter="[bufferExtent.Extent.Expand(2)]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="RunExternalCommand_10" />
                              <FlowStep.Next>
                                <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID5" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_4">
                                  <gwa1:ExitWorkflow sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ExitWorkflow_1" />
                                </FlowStep>
                              </FlowStep.Next>
                            </FlowStep>
                          </FlowStep.Next>
                        </FlowStep>
                      </FlowStep.Next>
                    </FlowStep>
                  </FlowStep.Next>
                </FlowStep>
              </FlowDecision.True>
              <FlowDecision.False>
                <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID6" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_9">
                  <gwa1:QueryTask sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="QueryTask_3" OutFields="*" OutSpatialReference="[wkid]" QueryServiceUrl="[retiredQueryServiceUrl]" Results="[ReturnedParcel]" ReturnGeometry="True" Where="[&quot;TaxKey = '&quot; &amp; id &amp; &quot;'&quot;]" />
                  <FlowStep.Next>
                    <FlowDecision x:Name="__ReferenceID8" Condition="[ReturnedParcel.Features.Count &gt; 0]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowDecision_2">
                      <FlowDecision.True>
                        <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID13" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_24">
                          <Sequence DisplayName="BufferSequence" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Sequence_6">
                            <Sequence.Variables>
                              <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Name="variable2" />
                              <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IEnumerable(esri:Graphic)" Name="bufferResult" />
                              <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:String" Default="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer" Name="geometryServiceUri" />
                              <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg:IList(esri:Graphic)" Name="bufferResult2" />
                            </Sequence.Variables>
                            <gwa1:BufferTask BufferSpatialReference="[wkid]" Distance="10" FeatureSet="[ReturnedParcel]" GeometryServiceUrl="http://maps.waukcogeo.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/Geometry/GeometryServer" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="BufferTask_3" OutSpatialReference="[wkid]" Results="[bufferResult]" Unit="[ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.LinearUnit.Foot]" />
                            <gwa1:ProjectTask FeatureSet="[bufferResult]" GeometryServiceUrl="[geometryServiceUri]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ProjectTask_2" Results="[bufferResult2]" SpatialReference="[new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.SpatialReference(32054)]" />
                            <Assign sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Assign_3">
                              <Assign.To>
                                <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Geometry">[bufferResultGeom]</OutArgument>
                              </Assign.To>
                              <Assign.Value>
                                <InArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Geometry">[bufferResult2.First().Geometry]</InArgument>
                              </Assign.Value>
                            </Assign>
                            <Assign sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Assign_4">
                              <Assign.To>
                                <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope">[bufferExtent]</OutArgument>
                              </Assign.To>
                              <Assign.Value>
                                <InArgument x:TypeArguments="esri:Envelope">[bufferResultGeom.Extent.Expand(2)]</InArgument>
                              </Assign.Value>
                            </Assign>
                          </Sequence>
                          <FlowStep.Next>
                            <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID15" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_23">
                              <gwa1:SelectFeatures ClearCollectionFirst="True" FeatureSet="[ReturnedParcel]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="SelectFeatures_4" LayerId="[retiredLayerID]" MapServiceId="[mapServiceID]" />
                              <FlowStep.Next>
                                <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID12" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_22">
                                  <gwa1:RunExternalCommand CommandName="HighlightEsriFeatureSet" CommandParameter="[ReturnedParcel]" DisplayName="Highlight Features" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="RunExternalCommand_13" />
                                  <FlowStep.Next>
                                    <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID14" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_21">
                                      <gwa1:RunExternalCommand CommandName="ZoomToExtent" CommandParameter="[bufferExtent.Extent.Expand(2)]" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="RunExternalCommand_14" />
                                      <FlowStep.Next>
                                        <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID7" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_10">
                                          <gwa1:ExitWorkflow sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ExitWorkflow_3" />
                                        </FlowStep>
                                      </FlowStep.Next>
                                    </FlowStep>
                                  </FlowStep.Next>
                                </FlowStep>
                              </FlowStep.Next>
                            </FlowStep>
                          </FlowStep.Next>
                        </FlowStep>
                      </FlowDecision.True>
                      <FlowDecision.False>
                        <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID2" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_2">
                          <gwa1:Alert sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="Alert_1" Text="[&quot;No parcels found in GIS for &quot; + id]" Title="No Parcels Found" />
                          <FlowStep.Next>
                            <FlowStep x:Name="__ReferenceID4" sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="FlowStep_8">
                              <gwa1:ExitWorkflow sap2010:WorkflowViewState.IdRef="ExitWorkflow_2" />
                            </FlowStep>
                          </FlowStep.Next>
                        </FlowStep>
                      </FlowDecision.False>
                    </FlowDecision>
                  </FlowStep.Next>
                </FlowStep>
              </FlowDecision.False>
            </FlowDecision>
          </FlowStep.Next>
        </FlowStep>
      </Flowchart.StartNode>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID0</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID1</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID2</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID3</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID4</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID5</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID6</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID7</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID8</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID9</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID10</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID11</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID12</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID13</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID14</x:Reference>
      <x:Reference>__ReferenceID15</x:Reference>
    </Flowchart>
    <sads:DebugSymbol.Symbol>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</sads:DebugSymbol.Symbol>
  </Sequence>
  <sap2010:WorkflowViewState.ViewStateManager>
    <sap2010:ViewStateManager>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="QueryTask_2" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="BufferTask_2" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,261">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="ProjectTask_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,161" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Assign_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,60">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Assign_2" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,60">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Sequence_5" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="SelectFeatures_2" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="RunExternalCommand_12" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="RunExternalCommand_10" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="ExitWorkflow_1" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_4">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">0,629</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,22</av:Size>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_15">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">0,554.5</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,51</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">100,605.5 100,629</av:PointCollection>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_20">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">0,474.5</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,51</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">100,525.5 100,554.5</av:PointCollection>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_1">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">0,404.5</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,51</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">100,455.5 100,474.5</av:PointCollection>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_18">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">10,324.02</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,51</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">110,375.02 100,375.02 100,404.5</av:PointCollection>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="QueryTask_3" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="BufferTask_3" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,261">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="ProjectTask_2" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,161" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Assign_3" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,60">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Assign_4" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="337,60">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="Sequence_6" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="SelectFeatures_4" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="RunExternalCommand_13" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51" />
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="RunExternalCommand_14" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,51">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="ExitWorkflow_3" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="200,22">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_10">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">250,749</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,22</av:Size>
          </scg:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      </sap2010:ViewStateData>
      <sap2010:ViewStateData Id="FlowStep_21">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <av:Point x:Key="ShapeLocation">250,674.5</av:Point>
            <av:Size x:Key="ShapeSize">200,51</av:Size>
            <av:PointCollection x:Key="ConnectorLocation">350,725.5
```

...

```
</Activity>
```

Comment: Sometimes the variable `e` is used in event handlers. The error message should be accompanied by a file name and line number. Can you post the actual error message?

Comment: I'm not sure that XML is the problem. Do you have a stack trace you can include? That will hopefully shed more light.

Comment: This is the only reference to an error in the Log Files. Should I check Event Viewer for something else? <Event Timestamp="2016-07-26T16:03:08.8461954-05:00" Level="ERROR" Identity="Guest"><Message>File not found: Resources/Styles/Custom/images/spriteArrows.png.</Message></Event>
<Event Timestamp="2016-07-26T16:03:08.847185-05:00" Level="DEBUG" Identity="Guest"><Message>HttpException: File not found: Resources/Styles/Custom/images/spriteArrows.png.
   at Geocortex.Essentials.Rest.Resources.ContentResourceBase.Init()
   at Geocortex.Essentials.Rest.Resources.ViewerContentResource.Init()